# Learning by example - terminology (?, :, etc)

Tags: c#, operators, terminology, ternary-operator

When you were a kid, did you ever ask your parents how to spell something and they told you to go look it up?  My first impression was always, "well if could look it up I wouldnt need help spelling it".  (yeah yeah I know phonetics)

...anyway, I was just looking at some code and I found an example like:

```
 txtbx.CharacterCasing = (checkbox.Checked) ? CharacterCasing.Upper : CharacterCasing.Normal;
```

I can figure out what this operation does, but obviously, I cant google for ? or : and I cant find them when searching for "c# operators", LINQ, Lambda expressions, etc.  So I have to ask this silly question so I can go start reading about it.

What are these operators?

Comment: Consider downloading the C# specification -- the Table of Contents is pretty handy for rapidly determining the names of things.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`?:` is the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28VS.80%29.aspx), and the best way to find out is to ask here!

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

> If condition is true, first expression is evaluated and becomes the result; if false, the second expression is evaluated and becomes the result. Only one of two expressions is ever evaluated.

It's extremely helpful for readability of assignments, when the entire expression is relatively short:

```
string name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Nickname) ? user.Fullname : user.Nickname
```

Is much easier and faster than:

```
string name = user.Fullname;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Nickname))
{
    name = user.Nickname;
}
```

Comment: are there any benefits (readability, performance, etc) to using conditional operators

Comment: @DataPimp readability. It's especially helpful with assignment (see my updated answer).

Comment: Haha, definitely StackOverflow is your best bet! I'd like to add that the ? : operator is a 'ternary' operator because it takes three operands (compare binary operator), and since it happens to be the only ternary operator in a lot of languages, it's also sometimes referred to as *the* ternary operator.

Comment: up one level shows you a list of all the operators which may be helpful for someone not familiar witht he language: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Funny thing is, I thought I was ready to get flamed for asking the question, "Whats ? mean"  :)

Answer (score 5):

`?` is an inline-`if` statement. This means that if `checkbox.Checked` is `true`, then `CharacterCasing.Upper` will be the value of the expression, otherwise `CharacterCasing.Normal` will be.

It works like this:

`type value = condition ? trueValue : falseValue;`

Comment: And it is called a ternary operator.  The OP can google that to find the answer.

Comment: Another one that you probably aren't aware of is the coalescing operator (??). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: This question (and the answers to it) is well worth a read too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c

Answer (score 3):

that is an inline if statement. "?" is the code for the if, ":" is the for the else.

Comment: It would have been way more easy for begineers if the syntax was an else rather than :!

Comment: @Kenny: "VB's `If...Then...End If` structure would arguably fit your definition, yet C# goes with `{` and `}` for readability and concision.

Answer (score 2):

The ? is also known as the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

Comment: "Ternary operator" just means "operator that takes three arguments", without specifying their purpose or meaning.

Comment: @Rex: This is true, but most languages only have one 3-arg operator, hence "THE ternary operator".  Even though it isn't specific, this terminology is commonly used to identify the ?: operator.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, it so happens that you can [search for "?:"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) on wikipedia and find this.

Note that it's also sometimes called "the" ternary operator, since its the only ternary (3-argument) operator in C-like languages.

Answer (score 1):

Btw.
As you are learning C# check out [?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28VS.80%29.aspx) It is sometimes much better alternative to ?:.

Consider:

```
Console.WriteLine(user.LastName ?? "no last name provided");
```

vs:

```
Console.WriteLine(user.LastName != null ? user.LastName : "no last name provided");
```

Comment: second expression should be: user.LastName != null ? user.LastName : "no last name provided"